# Autocomplete errors on internal exchange emails

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange, autocomplete

We recently switched the company from a hosted exchange to our own Exschange 2016 server. When we moved everything over we would get bouncebacks on internal emails. I found the cause of this to be Outlook's autocomplete, the solution was basically to remove the autocomplete entry and then recreate it and it would now point to the new server.

However today a new one crept up, the reply all button. When this is selected we are getting the same issue, despite the individual autocomplete entries being corrected already. How would I go about fixing this for all the employees?

Comment: What has your research effort shown using Google? Questions on SU or other stack exchange sites are expected to show some research effort on your part and should be included in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't post details on the bounceback but it sounds like it's because you are missing the legacyExchangeDN after the migration. The following Microsoft KB is for Office365 but works for on premise Exchange versions as well: [IMCEAEX non-delivery report](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2807779)

> To create an X500 proxy address for the old LegacyExchangeDN attribute for the user, make the following changes based on the recipient address in the NDR:

```
Replace any underscore character (_) with a slash character (/).
Replace "+20" with a blank space.
Replace "+28" with an opening parenthesis character.
Replace "+29" with a closing parenthesis character.
Delete the "IMCEAEX-" string.
Delete the "@mgd.domain.com" string.
Add "X500:" at the beginning.
```